# Why GetDate() shows current date - 2 days on MSSQL server?

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

MSSQL server is installed on windows 7 machine.
Say, the current system date on windows 7 is 24-01-2014.
I created one dummy table using sql given below:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATE
(
    NAME      VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    START_TIME      DATE,
    ROWTS           INT   DEFAULT 1 NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (NAME)
);
```

Then I inserted one record using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_DATE (NAME,START_TIME) VALUES ('TEST1',GetDate());
```

When I query this table, it shows START_TIME **2014-01-22**, which is 2 days before current date.

But when I query with following command:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME() AS SYSDATETIME,GETDATE() AS GETDATE;
```

It shows **SYSDATETIME --> 2014-01-22, and GETDATE --> 2014-01-24.**

Why is there 2 days of difference in date? What could be the possible reasons?

Comment: It gives me the correct date [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/46a01/1)

Comment: what version/service pack of sql server are you using?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the query and its result? There's something going on that is not apparent in the question.

Comment: I can not post screenshot as it is not allowed to share office work publicly.

Comment: How are you executing the query? In SSMS?

Comment: I am using squirrel db client.

Comment: @user3231271: I don't imagine any confidential data results in statement `SELECT SYSDATETIME() AS SYSDATETIME,GETDATE() AS GETDATE;` You can add a screen shot on that.

Comment: I tried attaching screenshot for this query. StackOverflow is not allowing me to do so. Message says: "You need atleast 10 reputation to post an image".

Comment: I checked my user profile. I have 1 reputation...

Comment: @mkumardev, upload it to http://imgur.com and post the link

Comment: Well i'm not sure how much this will help in this situation but the only difference in GETDATE() and SYSDATETIME() are the precision that they use;
GETDATE() returns a datetime 
SYSDATETIME() returns a datetime2(7)
so you would only see a difference in date if you was to be using milliseconds there should be no difference in the days.

Comment: @LukeFranklin - It is a known bug in some editions of the JDBC driver. See duplicate link above.

Comment: @MartinSmith well i never new that. thanks for pointing this out to me and it seems the logical answer to this question